# Solving a differential equation via variable substitution

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, substitution

Consider the following differential equation
$$
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))+g(u(t)), \ \ t\ge 0,
$$
where $x(0)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u(t)$ is an external input. Suppose that the functions $f$ and $g$ are such that the solution to the above equation exists and is unique.

> **Q.** By means of variable substitution $x(t)\mapsto z$, is it always possible to rewrite the above equation as
>   $$
> t=\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)+g(\tilde{u}(z))},
> $$
>   where $\tilde{u}(z)$ is some suitable function depending on $z$? If not, under which conditions is it possible?

My guess is that this is false since the external term $u(t)$ cannot in general be expressed as a function of $x(t)$, but I would like to have a confirmation by someone that has more experience than me on differential equations. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Despite what it seems, the answer to your question is affirmative *outside the vanishing points and under some mild regularity conditions* (customarily assumed to guarantee uniqueness of the solution) on the 1-dimensional vector field at the right side of your equation. To see why, let's consider the following Cauchy problem for a more general first order *non autonomous* ordinary differential equation: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t)=v(t,x) \\
x(t_0)=x_0\in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}

A standard sufficient condition for the uniqueness of the solution $x(t)$ of \eqref{1} is 
$$
v\in C^1(\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}), \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
as mentioned in [1], §2.3 p. 38, problem 5. If a *non vanishing condition*
$$
v(t_0,x_0)\neq 0 
$$
holds for some point $(t_0,x_0)\in\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}$, condition \eqref{2} implies that it holds for a [neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Neighbourhood_of_a_point) $U(t_0,x_0)$ of that point, thus
$$
v(t,x)>0\, \text{ or }\,v(t,x)<0 \quad\forall (t,x)\in U(t_0,x_0).
$$
Since $v$ the first derivative of $x$ according to the equation in \eqref{1}, this implies that $x(t)$ **is strictly monotonically increasing or decreasing** and thus **is injective and locally invertible on** $U_{t_0}=\{t\in \mathbb{R}_+|(t,x)\in U(t_0,x_0)\}$, with values in $U_{x_0}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|(t,x)\in U(t_0,x_0)\}$.

Its inverse function 
$$
x^{-1}:U_{x_0} \to U_{t_0}
$$
is such that
$$
x^{-1}(z)=t\in U_{t_0} \text{ for } z\in U_{x_0}\iff v(t,z)=v\big(x^{-1}(z),z\big),\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
and by using it is possible to prove the following analogue of the standard Barrow's formula ([1], §1.5 p. 19):
$$
t-t_0=\int\limits_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{v\big(x^{-1}(z),z\big)}.
\tag{4}\label{4}
$$
In your specific case, \eqref{3} leads to the following general formula for $\tilde{u}$:
$$
\tilde{u}(z)=u\circ x^{-1}(z)=u\big(x^{-1}(z)\big).
$$

**A few notes**

- Following your indication, I have left out any consideration about the existence and uniqueness of the solution to Cauchy problem \eqref{1} (and thus on your original problem): however the requirements on $v$ needed for proving existence and uniqueness play a role in deciding whether there exists or not formula \eqref{4}. Probably it is possible to prove it under even milder condition, i.e. $v\in C^{(0,1)}(\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R})$ (Lipschitz continuity).
- The above method is an adaption of the one that scholars of continuous mechanics use to make explicit the structure of some functionals by requiring their *material frame indifference*.

[1] Vladimir Igorevic Arnol'd, "*Ordinary differential equations*", various editions from MIT Press and from Springer-Verlag, MR1162307 Zbl 0744.34001.